# Zend Routing and Database Mapping

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is some background on the problem.

We have a database of vehicles.  The data is purchased from a third party and imported.  Some columns in the database have symbols in their values (Trade mark, Copyright etc...)

example

Kawasaki Ninja &reg &tm;.

We have a Controller which handles the displaying the vehicles from a database but one of the parameters from the route is used as a criteria in pulling data from the database.

So we will have routes that look like this

/Kawasaki/Ninja

which will display all Kawasaki Ninja bikes.  There is a single action in the controller which takes the values from the route Kawasaki and Ninja and generates a SQL statement to pull all Kawasaki Ninjas from the database.  Here is where the problem is the data in the database is not always going to be clean like I stated above it will have different symbols.

Is there a elegant solution to this where I can easily look up data in my database by using the Route that zend provides me.  Having the special characters in the URL isn't a valid solution according to the business rules so that has been ruled out.  We have also looked into cleaning the data in the database and removing any unwanted symbols.  That however would require changes to the way data is imported or having a script run through the database and do cleaning.  We would like to be able to leave the data in tact and avoid any type of wild card searches against the database.  This mapping needs to be able to be done both ways from the database to url and the url to database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Would it be possible for you to add a field to the database that was the cleaned version of the route?
So, for your example, put "/Kawasaki/Ninja" in the route field. This leaves the rest of your data intact.

Potentially faster would to be create two more tables. One that contained the routes with an integer id and another that mapped the route to the vehicles that matched. This would allow a vehicle to have multiple routes that would still map to it.